# How do I sort my music library based on PlayerPro's .m3u files?

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, music

I'm looking ti import my music library which is on my phone on to my computer. On my phone I use playerpro as my musicplayer and I've rated/sorted my music via there. Now I want to sort them the same way on my pc. Inside playerpro you can have playlists spanning multiple folders and PlayerPro uses files to save this information. An example of a file like this is:

ambient.m3u.ppo:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:251,Shockline - Alive
/6-5-2019/Shockline - Alive.mp3
#EXTINF:269,Noisia - The Entangled (Camo & Krooked Remix) [OUT NOW]
/6-5-2019/Noisia - The Entangled (Camo & Krooked Remix) [OUT NOW].mp3
#EXTINF:252,Purity Ring - Grandloves (DarkGrey & ObeyHim Remix)
/6-5-2019/Purity Ring - Grandloves (DarkGrey & ObeyHim Remix).mp3
#EXTINF:156,<unknown> - HMU (Esseks Remix)
/6-5-2019/HMU (Esseks Remix).mp3
#EXTINF:213,Spectrum - I Trusted You (feat. Dora Davis)
/6-5-2019/Spectrum - I Trusted You (feat. Dora Davis).mp3
#EXTINF:244,Bruno Mars - Locked Out Of Heaven (Major Lazer Remix)
/6-5-2019/Bruno Mars - Locked Out Of Heaven (Major Lazer Remix).mp3
#EXTINF:310,<unknown> - Polar
/6-5-2019/Polar.mp3
#EXTINF:301,ReduX - Endless
/5-5-2019/ReduX - Endless.mp3
#EXTINF:185,Midnight Tyrannosaurus - Omnic Harmony (Out Now on THA GOOSE DIARIES VOL 1)
/5-5-2019/Midnight Tyrannosaurus - Omnic Harmony (Out Now on THA GOOSE DIARIES VOL 1).mp3
#EXTINF:358,Zen Militia - Sleepy Walker
/5-5-2019/Zen Militia - Sleepy Walker.mp3
#EXTINF:161,<unknown> - Strange Man, White Van (FREE DOWNLOAD)
/5-5-2019/Strange Man, White Van (FREE DOWNLOAD).mp3
#EXTINF:260,<unknown> - Wanna Know You (ft. Holly Drummond)
/5-5-2019/Wanna Know You (ft. Holly Drummond).mp3
```

now as you can see there are a few folders (with dates as names) where the music files are stored. Now I would like to move the songs from each playlist to it's own folder, with the name of the playlist being the name of the folder.

Also PlayerPro allows you to rate each song. These ratings are not stored in a file however but in an "internal Database" which can't be accessed through the filesystem on android. You can, however, export these ratings to an XML file in the MediaMonkey format which looks like this:

```
...

  <mediaitem>
    <last-played/>
    <artist>JAGGS &amp; KEVU</artist>
    <track>Stop Me (OUT NOW!)</track>
    <album>6-5-2019</album>
    <duration/>
    <rating>3</rating>
    <play-count/>
    <skip-count>1</skip-count>
  </mediaitem>
  <mediaitem>
    <last-played/>
    <artist>Jarvis</artist>
    <track>Rowdy **BASSRUSH PREMIERE**</track>
    <album>6-5-2019</album>
    <duration/>
    <rating>4</rating>
    <play-count/>
    <skip-count>1</skip-count>
  </mediaitem>
  <mediaitem>
    <last-played/>
    <artist>Jauz &amp; Snails</artist>
    <track>Motherfuckers (LUCHI Remix)</track>
    <album>6-5-2019</album>
    <duration/>
    <rating>2</rating>
    <play-count/>
    <skip-count>1</skip-count>
  </mediaitem>
  <mediaitem>
    <last-played/>
    <artist>Jayceeoh &amp; Lit Lords</artist>
    <track>2 Tha Bank</track>
    <album>6-5-2019</album>
    <duration/>
    <rating>5</rating>
    <play-count/>
    <skip-count>1</skip-count>
  </mediaitem>
  <mediaitem>
    <last-played>1557132160000</last-played>
    <artist>Jayceeoh &amp; The Oddictions</artist>
    <track>Alright Ft. Britt Daley (Jayceeoh &amp; Lit Lords VIP)</track>
    <album>6-5-2019</album>
    <duration/>
    <rating>3</rating>
    <play-count>1</play-count>
    <skip-count/>
  </mediaitem>
  <mediaitem>
    <last-played/>
    <artist>JayKode x Party Theives</artist>
    <track>Origin [FAWKS FLIP]</track>
    <album>6-5-2019</album>
    <duration/>
    <rating>4</rating>
    <play-count/>
    <skip-count>3</skip-count>
  </mediaitem>
....
```

I'd like to apply these rating values to the windows rating system for mp3's (the ones which show up in windows media player). A major problem is that there is no filename stored here but only an artist and title entry. Also the ablum entry is actually the folder in which the file is.

I've tried importing this file into MediaMonkey however it's unable to import any information for any song.

Are there any scripts/programs to automate the process for adding ratings to the files and then making the folders from the playlist files?

Answer (score 0):

To add the ratings to the songs in WMP, there's the [Metadata Backup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metadatabackup/) tool that can import/export all of WMP's library info (including ratings) from/to an XML file. However, the XML format used by Metadata Backup is completely different from the format generated by PlayerPro, so you would still need a way to convert one format to the other.